# When dom element has text remove in it, remove the whole element

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I'm currently using wordpress and my theme creates automatic a menu where all the items get "-" depending on the levels. Pretty annoying I know. Im trying to fix it but really couldn't just remove the "-" with the spaces, so I replaced all the options values. So here's my question:

I wanna remove a whole div with the text "remove" in it. I tried

```
$('.hasCustomSelect').has('.menu-item:contains("remove")').remove();
```

and some other things I found online but can't get it to work.

I created a small codepen to show it:
http://codepen.io/denniswegereef/pen/NGGrgR

Comment: jquery not defined error in console.

Comment: What does the line of code above do? Does it throw any error?

Comment: I have no issues at all, the code just doesn't do anything :(

Comment: so is the only text in the div's you want to remove, "remove"?

Comment: Why not just fix the text with your script?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".hasCustomSelect option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() == "remove") // If 'remove' is not the only text in the div to remove then replace with $(this).text().indexOf("remove") > -1
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Note that I replaced `.menu-item` with `option` because in your codepen you were adding the new options to the select without the `menu-item` class. But if in the real scenario the `div`s have that class, you should be fine with: `$(".hasCustomSelect .menu-item")`

Answer (score 1):

This is a slight edit of Diego's solution:

```
$(".hasCustomSelect option").each(function() {
    if ($(this).text() === "remove") // Match type && match string
        $(this).remove();
});
```

Comment: Both operators `==` and `===` are case sensitive: http://jsfiddle.net/paska/w8qducny/